# How do I apply a .patch in JOOMLA?

Tags: content-management-system, joomla, patch

I have a **bug_fix.patch** file for Joomla version 1.5.22 and I am trying to apply it. How does one go about doing such a thing?

One article I read mentions dumping it into the root directory of my Joomla site... But how is it picked up by Joomla? It doesn't make much sense to me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to upgrade your Joomla version (which it sounds like you are) then you should download something like "1.5.22 to 1.5.23 Upgrade Package" from http://www.joomla.org/download.html.
You then unzip it and upload all the files.

The bug_fix.patch file is for developers working on the Joomla project, see http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html for an example.

Comment: I'm not trying to upgrade from 1.5.22 to 1.5.23 I am just trying to apply a patch to my current version. However you're article sorted the issue. Thx